# Meteor 0.6.0 and Collection API

Tags: meteor

Upgraded to the latest 0.6.0 of meteor and Collection API is not define, meteor does not start correctly any more:

ReferenceError: CollectionAPI is not defined

I copy pasted collectionapi to app "packages" folder, but still does not run. Is there anything else I have to do, to use Collection API with latest meteor 0.6.0?

meteor add collectionapi - says: collectionapi: already using

Thanks in advance for any kind of information and help!

Comment: It might be a bug with the new variable scoping, it needs to be updated to work, or if you can edit the code find where `var CollectionAPI` is and change it to `Collection API`

Answer (score 1):

<del>I'm not sure copying and pasting packages is a good idea. Have you tried reinstalling it with `meteor remove collectionapi` and then adding it again?</del>

Update: I seem to be getting the same problem with one of my packages, [chartjs](https://github.com/donskifarrell/meteor-chartjs). It's now giving a similar error to yours, saying `ReferenceError: Chart is not defined`. Previously `Chart` was scoped to the window, so it could be accessed in my client JS files. It must be due to the scoping changes in 0.6.0, but I'm not sure yet how to resolve it - probably the package itself needs updating.

Update 2: Yup, akshat was dead right, the JS file at the heart of the chartjs package needed the `var Chart` changing to just `Chart` so it would be scoped to the `window` object. Have sent [a pull request](https://github.com/donskifarrell/meteor-chartjs/pull/2) to the package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks for answers. Fix is also available for download in CollectionAPI github:

https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi/pull/12